# How to disable apps without uninstalling them?

Tags: android-management-api

We have a use case where an app is only allowed to run for a certain amount of time. The Android Management API does not seem to allow profiles to trigger things offline, so we're ok with pushing a profile at a specific time. However, I don't see a policy setting to simply disable the app without uninstalling it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Doing a bit more research, it looks like this was possible with the `complianceRules` policy setting. However, looks like this was deprecated recently on the May 7 release (see https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes). Appreciate any feedback/help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how I missed it, but just noticed the `disabled` property under ApplicationPolicy...

https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#ApplicationPolicy